# static variables with multi Client

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

I receive messages via socket. if tokens[0] ==MSG I want to save the source IP and Port ( they are stored in tokens[3] and tokens[4] ) and send a message to the server. When the server will answer , token[0] will contain the server answer so the last else will be excuted and I need the sourceIP and the Port but they are renitilased  and contain Null. I tried to use static it work when I have one Client but with multiple Client I have problems ..

```java
public static InetAddress msgAdr = null;
public static int msgPort = 0;

if("HOPEN".equals(tokens[0])) {
    hopen(IPAddress, port);
}
else if("HCLOSE".equals(tokens[0])) {
    hclose(IPAddress, port);
}
else if("MSG".equals(tokens[0])) {
    msgAdr = InetAddress.getByName(tokens[3]);
    msgPort = Integer.parseInt(tokens[4].trim());
    System.out.println("**********" + msgAdr + "  " + msgPort);
    msg(IPAddress ,port);  // send message to the server
}
else
{
    System.out.println("-------" + msgAdr + "  " + msgPort);
    send(sentence, msgAdr, msgPort); //send answer to the Client
}
```

Comment: why don't you define them as local variables there

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean.. I extract them when I get the First MSG and then if I don't recive MSG , HOPEN or HCLOSE I want to use them

Comment: Use them where?  Do you mean that you want to signal the address/port data to another thread?  If so, you cannot communicate the data out by simply stuffing it into shared statics where it will get overwritten/sliced/someOtherUB'd.  You need safe, reliable inter-thread comms/signaling.  Please explain in more detail what you are trying to achieve.